# how to retrieve partial objects from object array in a field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose schema like -

```
db.foo.insert({one:'a',friends:[{two:'b',three:'c'},{two:'d',three:'e'},{two:'f',three:'G'}]})
```

now what i want is two retrieve only the `'two'` part of `friends` array
that is I want to find an array of all the values of `two` in each object in `friends` array
Is such a projection possible in mongodb where in the output looks like -

```
['b','d','f']
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK I just edited the question to include the expected answer.

Comment: No, they are unique values. I am inserting that way only. Sorry forgot to mention that earlier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aggregate` is your answer

```
db.foo.aggregate({"$project" : {"two" : "$friends.two"}}).result
```

there is another way to do that (getting distinct values)

```
db.foo.aggregate([      
    {'$project': {  
                    union:{$setUnion:["$friends.two"]}
                 }
    }
]).result;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [`distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct):

```js
 db.foo.distinct('friends.two')
```

Output:

```js
[
  "b",
  "d",
  "f"
]
```

Comment: It says Error:Distinct is not implemented. in the try.mongodb.org. but worked fine on my desktop. Thanks for the answer