# Fetch Specific Fields from Specific Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Suppose I have a database of Patients, each of which might have more than one physical address, so the database has an Array of Addresses. I want to find a certain Patient and return only a certain field from each address in the array of Addresses.

If I use this, I successfully get every address (array member) and every detail (street, number, city, zip, etc.) of each address:

```
db.Patients.find( { "LastName": "Smith" }, { "Addresses": 1 } )
```

I try this, hoping to get only the City of the first address

```
db.Patients.find( { "LastName": "Smith" }, { "Addresses.0.City": 1 } )
```

or I try this (to simplify things), hoping to get all the details of (only) the first address

```
db.Patients.find( { "LastName": "Smith" }, { "Addresses.0": 1 } )
```

Instead, in both of those cases, I get the Patient record with an empty document for Addresses. But I don't understand why?

Thanks!

Comment: Neither do we. Perhaps you should show your document in your question.  [Please Edit Your Question to show the document.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44615436/edit)

Comment: Have you tried `db.Patients.find( { "LastName": "Smith" }, { "Addresses.City": 1 } )` ?

Comment: Looking at your previous question [Retrieve only some fields from sub-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600321/retrieve-only-some-fields-from-sub-document) which was actually renamed by myself since you were calling that structure "an array", it would seem logical that you have not learned that lesson. Something like `{ "Addresses": { "Home": { "street": "...", "city": "..." }, "Work": { ... } } }` as I suspect you actually have, is **not** an array. Which explains why the notation you are using in your projection returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks Veeram! for helping me, I really learned something. If I could improve your reputation for this comment, I would.

Comment: Also Thanks to Neil! I really made some big bone-head mistakes, but with your corrections, I learn some things I didn't know before. I really appreciate it and learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 0):

If want to get only the address (or its detail/children) for the particular address in the array that it matches, I don't think it's possible in MongoDB. You'll have to rely on application side matching.

If what you want to get is only a `projection` of a particular address field, then what you're doing is already on the right track.

The below query does not work because you're projecting the `field` `Address.0`, which does not exist in your database. You can project `Address.city` or `Address.vicinity`, but it will not return you only the one that it matches from the query.

```
db.Patients.find( { "LastName": "Smith" }, { "Addresses.0": 1 } )
```

This one will work although it will return all addresses in the document that matches your query

```
db.Patients.find( { "LastName": "Smith" }, { "Addresses.City": 1 } )
```